# How to get the direct download link to the file, in the Chrome downloads (chrome://downloads) via selenium and Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

How can I get the download link which was **caught** by Chrome in Selenium Python3? I mean getting the link that I can get in the **chrome://downloads** page in which the link is displayed right under  the download file name. My purpose is to get the download link in a page where it will redirect to the download link after clicking the submit button of a POST form. (I don't want to download the file).

Actually I've made a script to **scrape** the link in the chrome://downloads page and then cancel & remove the download. But it is totally useless when using it on an Ubuntu VPS where I have to enable headless mode, which make chrome://downloads inaccessible (is it? I requested the page with Selenium and it did not return anything but a blank page)

How can I get the direct download link as the page doesn't have any <a> tags with a *href* attribute to the download link, but it will redirect to the link after I clicked the submit button and Chrome will catch it?

Thank you very much for your time and efforts!

Comment: can you please look at how link is generated? maybe, it can generate via JS or any dynamic id. you can look at that and if it's possible to generate with the help of HTML content of selenium.

Comment: Ummm, it seems that there is a hidden field with some weird data that will be sent to the form action after I click the button, then it will redirect me to the direct link.